# Laravel API confused POST method with GET method

Tags: java, php, android, rest, laravel-4

I can't to consume my Laravel 4 API with an android app. **But I'm not able to do that**

This is my `routes.php`

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function(){
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'namespace' => 'api\v1'], function(){
        Route::resource('person', 'PersonsRestController', array('only' => array('store', 'index')));
    });
});
```

And this is my `PersonsRestController.php`

```
namespace api\v1;


class PersonsRestController extends \BaseController {


    // The method is GET
    public function index() {
     dd("Index: ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
    }

    // The method is POST
    public function store() {
      dd("Store: ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);

    }

}
```

I tried to make an STORE operation (POST http method), But I always get the message of INDEX

I use this code for test my API rest:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("http://foo.com/api/v1/person/");
        Map<String, Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        params.put("name", "Freddie the Fish");
        params.put("email", "fishie@seamail.example.com");
        params.put("reply_to_thread", 10394);
        params.put("message", "Shark attacks in Botany Bay have gotten out of control. We need more defensive dolphins to protect the schools here, but Mayor Porpoise is too busy stuffing his snout with lobsters. He's so shellfish.");

        StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
            if (postData.length() != 0) {
                postData.append('&');
            }
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            postData.append('=');
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
        }
        byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

        Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        for (int c = in.read(); c != -1; c = in.read()) {
            System.out.print((char) c);
        }
    }
```

Source of code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21657510/4359029

I hope someone can help me with my problem...

**EDIT:**

I also tried with this directly:

```
Route::post('test', 'MyTestController@testMethod');
```

but i get the next error: `Server returned HTTP response code: 405 for URL: http://foo.bar/api/laravel`

**So laravel doesnt found my post route**

Comment: As I see in the docs, store use the POST method in Laravel 4.2. I make a request to store in my code...

Comment: Have you changed the error message or does it really return: `http://foo.bar/api/laravel`? :) You have no route defined for `api/laravel`.